# (JS) Basic question- return in if statement

Tags: javascript

I'm new for learning Javascript, and have encountered a problem that I cannot figure out it's rationale in an online course.  Please take a look on the code below.

```
function palindrome(word){ 
  let backwardWord = "";
  for (letter of word){
    // Adding letter at the beginning of the backward string
    backwardWord = letter + backwardWord;
}
  if (word.toLowerCase() === backwardWord.toLowerCase())
    return true
  else
    return false  
}
palindrome('racecar');
```

As you may know, this function aims to find if the string reads the same in forward or backward.

My question is, for what I know, if statement requires {} in order to run, and return can only be used in function, not a if statement.  Then why there are no {} in the if statement, and why a return could be used in the code above?

I've tried to rewrite a function using the same format, but it returns undefined rather than true.

```
let a=1
function test(){
if (a===1)
    return true
  else
    return false  
}
```

Thanks for anyone who answer this question, that will help a lot as I was puzzling for the past 0.5 hour and can't .

Comment: `if statement requires {} in order to run,` no

Comment: Thanks, the more code I read, I know more about JS and observe {} is not necessary at the end.

Comment: Note `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }` is an antipattern anyway - you can just `return word.toLowerCase() === backwardWord.toLowerCase())`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the second function is running and returning true

```js
let a=1
function test(){
if (a===1)
    return true
  else
    return false  
}

console.log(test());
console.log(typeof(test()));
```

If you have 1 line code after `if`, {} are not necessary.

And here is your first code. Better use
`for (let letter of word)`

```js
function palindrome(word){ 
    let backwardWord = "";
    for (let letter of word){
      backwardWord = letter + backwardWord;
  }
    if (word.toLowerCase() === backwardWord.toLowerCase()){
        console.log(backwardWord);
        return true;
    }
    else
      return false  
  }

console.log(palindrome('racecar'));
```

And last, `return` statement will get you out of the function immediately. You are returning true which has a type `boolean`, you can see using `typeof()` function in the second code.

Comment: Even better, use `for (const …`

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, it really helps! I can also apply this into other code I've read.

Answer (score 1):

When there is only one line inside a block then {} can be omitted.
for example:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
 print(i)
}
```

can be written as:

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 print(i)
```

As for your second option, undefined is shown because you have defined your function, but never called it or used it. If you type

```
test()
```

in the next line of your code then you will get `true` as a answer.

Comment: Good to know another way of coding this, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are allowed to `return` from anywhere within a function. `return`, much like `break`, immediately leaves whatever block it is executing.

Comment: Thanks! I start to realize this when I go through more code.

Answer (score 0):

Attention to this post! In JavaScript, you could use such syntax if there is 1 line in the statement! However, it is better to use `{}`

Couldn't say why you would be getting undefined, but it is so that one line after an `if` or `else`/`else if` statement is not required to be in square brackets for blocks.

Translating the code to human language to specify:

```
// human language there
if the word in all lowercase is the same as the word in all uppercase:
  the function returns true;
else:
  the function returns false;
```

The if...else statement did not return on its own, but just hosted the return for the needed function.